# Can't enter Gnus folder because *Group* buffer read-only

Tags: buffers, gnus

I have a working Gnus setup for email on one machine.  I am now trying to create slightly more modular setup on a second machine.  When I start Gnus on the second machine, mail is read and the group buffer appears as I would expect, but if I try to enter a folder, I get the following error:

```
Buffer is read-only: #<buffer *Group*>
```

I assume this is somehow connected to the fact that I am trying to run Emacs and Gnus out of a non-standard directory (using [Chemacs](https://github.com/plexus/chemacs2)).  Does anyone have any idea how to debug this? What variables should I have a look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an error in my new set up.  The old setup had

```
(add-hook 'gnus-group-mode-hook 'gnus-topic-mode)
```

I tried to achieve the same thing via `use-package`'s `:hook` with

```
(use-package 'gnus
 :config
 ... 
 :hook (gnus-group-mode gnus-topic-mode))
```

but I misunderstood the `:hook` syntax.  Thus, I was incorrectly trying to add the two modes as hooks to `gnus`.  D'oh.

So instead I just put

```
(add-hook 'gnus-group-mode-hook 'gnus-topic-mode))
```

in the `:config` block.

Comment: The `use-package` `:hook` syntax is indeed somewhat counter-intuitive and has been a source of problems on the Emacs SE in the past. Cave canem!

Comment: How did you fix it? By going back to the explicit `add-hook`?

Comment: Yes.  I just put ```(add-hook 'gnus-group-mode-hook 'gnus-topic-mode))``` in the ```:config``` block.

Comment: Can you add that to the answer? It would make the answer complete, not depending on a comment (that might disappear).

Comment: Thank you for editing the answer!